# If $(a_n)$ is the sequence of non zero real numbers such that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is a constant, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is a geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-writing

Let $(a_n)$ the sequence of non zero real numbers such that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is a constant. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is a geometric series.

I would like to know if my proof holds and have a feedback, please.

Let $k\in \mathbf{R}^*$ a constant of $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Then, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=k$. Then, we can define the sequence $(a_n)$ recursively: $a_{n+1}=a_n\cdot k$.

First, note that $a_n=(a_n-a_{n-1})+...+(a_1-a_0)+a_0$ and that $\forall p\ge1$:

$a_p-a_{p-1}=k(a_{p-1}-a_{p-2})=...=k^{p-1}(a_1-a_0)$.

Thus,

$a_n=k^{n-1}(a_1-a_0)+k^{n-2}(a_1-a_0)+...+a_1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=(a_1-a_0)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}k^n+a_0$. We conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is a geometric series.

Comment: Personally, I would conclude that $(a_n)$ is a geometric sequence from $a_{n+1} = a_n \cdot k$, as I take the satisfaction of recurrence relations of this form to be the very definition of a geometric sequence. Geometric series are just infinite sums of geometric sequences, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a geometric series.

Comment: A simpler way to see this is by noting that $$
a_n  = \frac{{a_n }}{{a_{n - 1} }} \cdot \frac{{a_{n - 1} }}{{a_{n - 2} }} \cdots \frac{{a_2 }}{{a_1 }} \cdot a_1  = k \cdot k \cdots k \cdot a_1  = k^{n - 1} a_1 .
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What to have done is correct but unnecessarily complicated. (No point in using the differences $a_p-a_{p-1}$). Use induction to show that $a_n= a_1 k^{n-1}$. So $\sum k^{n}=\sum a_1k^{n-1}$ which is a geometric series.

Comment: Thank you for an answer!

Answer (score 1):

$$A_{n+1}=k A_n$$
$$A_1=k A_0$$
$$A_2= k A_1$$
$$A_3=k A_2$$
...............
$$A_{n-1}=k A_{n-2}$$
$$A_{n}=k A_{n-1}$$
Multiplying them we get
$$A_n=k^n A_0.$$
Which$nth$ term of a GP. GP